# What is the pI of lysine tripeptide?

Tags: biochemistry, ph, amino-acids

> What the the $\mathrm{pI}$ of a tripeptide of lysine?
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{l|ccc}
> \hline
> \text{Group} & \ce{Lys{-}α{-}NH3+} & \ce{Lys{-}ε{-}NH3+} & \ce{Lys{-}α{-}COOH} \\
> \hline
> \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} & 8.0 & 10.5 & 2.2 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

I have written out the tripeptide, and I know when the hydrogens would come off of it depending on the $\mathrm{pH}.$ I know it has to do with the $\ce{α{-}NH3+}$ and the $\ce{ε{-}NH3+}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{pI} &= \frac{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{Lys{-}α{-}NH3+}) + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{Lys{-}ε{-}NH3+})}{2} \\
  &= \frac{8.0 + 10.5}{2} \\
  &= 9.25,
\end{align}
$$
but it was incorrect. Can anyone please help and explain the process to me?

[Swiss-Prot — Compute pI/Mw calculator](https://web.expasy.org/compute_pi/) gives $\mathrm{pI} = 10.30$ for `KKK` sequence in single letter code.

Comment: The tripeptide has 1+3 NH2 and 1 COOH. Calculate the average partial charge for each of them as function of [H+] and of respective acidity constant. And then calculate [H+] resp. pH when their charges are balanced with zero net charge.

Comment: Another thing is acidity constants for alpha NH2 and COOH will be different, compared to a single lysine, as the peptidic bond has different induction effect than amino or carboxy group. But the task may ignore this.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is not enough data to provide an exact answer theoretically.
You can figure out an *estimate value* by virtually titrating the tripeptide and figuring out after what step an isolectric point likely situates:

$$
\def\VEQ{{\scriptsize-\ce{H+}}{\Large\downharpoonleft\!\!\upharpoonright}\scriptsize{+\ce{H+}}}
\begin{array}{rcc}
\mathrm{pH} < 2.2 &\quad &\ce{H3\overset{+}{N}-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-COOH} \\
  & & \VEQ \\
2.2 < \mathrm{pH} < 8.0 &\quad &\ce{H3\overset{+}{N}-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-COO-} \\
  & & \VEQ \\
8.0 < \mathrm{pH} < 10.5 &\quad &\ce{H2N-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-\overset{+}{Lys}-COO-}\\
  & & \VEQ \\
10.5 < \mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{pI} &\quad &\ce{H2N-\overset{+}{[Lys-Lys-Lys]}-COO-}\\
\end{array}
$$

As you can see, the formal net zero charge doesn't occur between any given $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s.
Rather, at the highest $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{Lys{-}ε{-}NH3+}) = 10.5$ the tripeptide is still going to have $ 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 -1 = +0.5$ formal charge considering $50\,\%$ deprotonation of residue amine groups at $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ and $-1$ charge at the $\ce{-COO^-}$ group.

This implies that $\mathrm{pI}$ of trilysine must be slightly higher, about $10.8:$

[image: Titration curve for trilysine. Drawn in Inkscape 1.1]

For polylysines $\mathrm{pI}$ should increase with the chain length.
[ThermoFisher's Peptide Analyzing Tool](https://www.thermofisher.com/ru/ru/home/life-science/protein-biology/peptides-proteins/custom-peptide-synthesis-services/peptide-analyzing-tool.html) suggests theoretical $\mathrm{pI}$ values of $11.0,$ $11.2$ and $11.3$ for tetra-, penta- and heptalysine, respectively.
This tool, however, refuses to calculate isoelectric points for tripeptides (`Input sequence is too short`).
This can be an indication of insufficient quality of applied algorithm resulting in apparently wrong data suggested by Swiss-Prot in your question.

Note that we didn't corrected $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values for the tripeptide.
I wouldn't assume they change drastically, but it's not the identical values either.